# Logic Analyser for Mac environment

Tags: mac, logic-analyzer

I am wondering if anyone can recommend a logic analyser for a Apple Mac environment with similar features as the SCANALOGIC 2 PRO around the same price would be great as well.

or some thing that is similar, what type of features am I after for working with SPI and I2C. Fairly new to the Digital electronics

[Beginner's logic analyzer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/beginners-logic-analyzer) is all PC based.

Was just wondering if anyone knows of any that work with Mac at all. that aren't $199+ dollars

Answer (score 8):

I use the [Bus Pirate](http://code.google.com/p/the-bus-pirate/) and the [Open Logic Sniffer](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer) (both top links in [Beginner's logic analyzer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/beginners-logic-analyzer)) with OSX.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [Saleae's Logic](http://www.saleae.com/logic/) with success and it works on Linux, OSX and Windows (I've only used the first two). It's cheap, very, very small and has a few useful analyzers built it.

Comment: This is a really good product and works great on the Mac.