# Logic Analyzer / Oscilloscope Suggestions

Tags: microcontroller, avr, oscilloscope, logic-analyzer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beginner's logic analyzer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/beginners-logic-analyzer)

I am a beginner in electronics. Been tinkering with micro controllers for about 2-3 months now. At this point I find the need for a logic analyzer / oscilloscope to help me while debugging my projects.

The only time I have used an oscilloscope before was in university lab class (instrumentaion).

I was hoping you could help me with what I need to look for in one (specifications .. i am not even sure what specs are there for such tool) and give some suggestions for some good on considering the factors below

1. **Cost** - dont want to invest too much at this point
2. **Portability** - i dont have a workshop setup so portability is good
3. **Use** - would be using it mainly to debug micro controller projects

on a side note, ability to connect and transfer data to a PC would be awesome.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/beginners-logic-analyzer